# Remove only zero after decimal sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, rounding

Consider the following numbers.

```
7870.2
8220.0
```

I need to remove decimal points if the value ends with `.0`. If it ends with `.2` then it should keep the value as it is.

I have used `ceiling` but it removes all the values after decimal.

How can I write a select query in which I can add some condition for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `right` within a `case` statement and:

```
DECLARE @val decimal(5,1)
SET @val =  7870.0

Select  
Case 
   When right(@val,1)<> '0' then
        cast(@val as varchar) 
   else 
        cast(cast(@val as int) as varchar)
End
```

**output:** 7870

**EDIT:** I could write :

```
Case 
   When right(@val,1)<> '0' then
        @val 
   else 
        cast(@val as int) -- or floor(@val)
End
```

**but** because return type of case statement is the [highest precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) type from the set of given types, so the output for second version is: 7870.0 not 7870, that's why I convert it to i.e varchar in when clauses, and it can be converted outside of case statement,  I mean cast ((case when...then...else... end) as datatype)

Comment: I cannot harcode the `decimal(5,1)` because the `5` may increase.

Comment: it is a sample(the declare part), you don't need to hardcode it.

Comment: `SELECT  
UPPER(MACH_NAME) AS MACHINE_NAME,
ROUND(SUM(f.EVENT_PAYLOAD),2) AS PAYLOAD,
(SUM(f.EVENT_NOMINAL_PAYLOAD)) AS NOMINAL_PAYLOAD,
Case 
   When RIGHT(PAYLOAD,1)<> '0' then
        CAST(PAYLOAD as varchar) 
   else 
        CAST(CAST(PAYLOAD as int) as varchar)
End`
I am trying to do something like this. But not working

Comment: I see you've used an alias inside cast and right function, use actual value I mean use "ROUND(SUM(f.EVENT_PAYLOAD),2)"

Comment: I suggest you explicitly case to varchar before using right. Implicit casts are a bad habit to break.

Comment: Agree, but my focus was on general alg, and don't want to use too much casts. specially it does not matter if be used in simple and none complicated queries

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking you should *not* do this in your dB. This is an app or reporting side operation. The dB is made to store and query information. It is not made to format/string manipulate information.

Comment: I don't see any harm in this conversion if done correctly. You are assuming this is a string manipulation, which is doesn't have to be. The currently chosen answer is just a bad example of how it could be done

Comment: Its not that your be can't do it or that it would destroy it if you did. But you ultimately are using SQL to do your presentation logic, and that is simply a bad idea architecturally. App and reporting tiers have great tools to format numbers, format dates, and can do so all in a scalable manner while not affecting what you store, or what you get back from your store. Its a pretty classic separation of concerns problem.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. You have not tried to solve the question

Comment: I have. I am saying it shouldn't be done. He may not like that answer, but it is the correct one. Blindly answering questions with flawed approaches because that was how the askers are doing things doesn't help them improve as developers.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the number as a [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ms173773.aspx), using float(24) to increase precision:

```
DECLARE @t table(number decimal(10,1))
INSERT @t values(7870.2),(8220.0)

SELECT cast(number as float(24))
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
7870,2
8220
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below goes a sample:

```
declare @1 decimal(4,3)
select @1 = 2.9

select case when SUBSTRING (PARSENAME(@1,1), 1, 1) = 0 then FLOOR(@1) else @1 end
```

Change the @1 in the select statement with your database field name.

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2185)

Comment: This will give `2.0` for `2.0` with `SQL Server`, SQLFIDDLE's presantation layer shows that 2.0 as 2.

Comment: @Farhęg, sorry for the late response, I'm using Floor to get the integer part, hence it would be 2 and not 2.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be simple:

```
SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, PAYLOAD)
```

Comment: Your code gives a wrong result. I believe this is the answer you are looking for SELECT IIF(PAYLOAD % 1 =0, FORMAT(PAYLOAD, 'F0'), FORMAT(PAYLOAD, 'F1'))

Comment: Thanks. I corrected my answer. Just using CONVERT works

Comment: yes, the answer is that simple. But same answer was already posted by me